# How to get size (in bytes) of documents fields in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have collection of documents (`products_entity`).

```
ID | TYPE | CONTENT_DATA
```

I can query `db.getCollection('products_entity').find({type: "comment"})` to get my documents by `type`.

I would like to now size of all `CONTENT_DATA` fields returned from my query `db.getCollection('products_entity').find({type: "comment"})`.

It is possible and how can I do it?

Or should I create one extra column called `size` fill it on create/update and get sum of this fields?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [$strLenBytes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/strLenBytes/index.html) or [$strLenCP](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/strLenCP/)

```
db.products_entity.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      size: {
        $strLenBytes: "$CONTENT_DATA"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/f1OHF6lOJ_S)